# Не загружается parrot os

Tags: linux, swap, parrot-os

Ошибки при загрузке parrot os

Ноутбук Lenovo ideapad 110 15 ast 80 tr и внешний диск kreolz

BTRFS error (device sdc5) : parrent transid verfy failed on 761806848 wanted 27839 found 27865

Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlife:amdgpu_b10

Failed to activate swap /swapfile

Failed to start Load AppAromor profiles

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46472439/13970074

Comment: Для этого нужен терминал , а у меня при загрузке даже через recovery вываливается ошибка и ничего сделать нельзя